# How can I set a launcher to start an application in a specific desktop

Tags: kubuntu, shortcuts

I've got a bunch of desktops set up for specific purposes. I'd really like to be able to tell an app what desktop it should launch in.

I can't find any options for that, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

In Kubuntu, you can change your Activity and have a different one for each desktop. If you  use folder view then you can have a  different folder for each desktop and in that folder you could make a link that would only be visible for that folder view. It can be really confusing for most people, but  I've done it with a different wallpaper and a different folder view on for four different desktops.

Here's how I would do it: Right click on the Desktop, choose Activities. Click on the Desktop in the ribbon at the bottom and choose new activity. You choose folder view and set the location as a different folder from in your home directory. You could create folders like Desktop1, Desktop2, etc. Then drag whatever files or applications that you want to the desktop and choose Link Here.