# How can I lock application windows to a certain virtual desktop?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, compiz, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set a launcher to start an application in a specific desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4485/how-can-i-set-a-launcher-to-start-an-application-in-a-specific-desktop)

I want to keep Pidgin, Skype, and a few other applications on a certain virtual desktop. How can I go about doing this, so that when I open these applications from my "primary" virtual desktop, the windows will appear in the other virtual desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I do it in 11.04. I hope it would be same for you.

Go to compiz settings manager-> Window managment -> Place Windows -> Fixed Windows placements. In the section of "Windows with fixed viewport" click New. Click on "+". Click on Grab and then click the window you want to be placed on specific descktop. Click "Add". Set the value of "X Viewport Positions" to the desired desktop number. That's all.

Comment: For me in 16.04 I need to ensure the windows aren't fully fullscreen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num5</kbd>) and I need to pick the last option in the dropdown of the criteria settings (the dialog after hitting the "+" button) - in my german version "Fenstertitel" instead of "Fenstername" - window title instead of window name.

Comment: It should be noted that on a dual-head/multi-monitor setup you will need to also add the windows to the "windows with fixed positions" list to ensure them popping up on the desired display and the "windows with fixed placement mode" for always fullscreen - although fully fullscreen does not appear possible!

Comment: And third comment is the charm: getting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (launch terminal) to open in fullscreen required activated the module "Window Rules" and putting name=gnome-terminal-server in the list of "maximized" in that module, the other windows (I tried) worked well enough with the "Window Placement"-placement-mode "maximize", but not the terminal shortcut!